# dispay image and video from database with react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

hey guys am trying to display my video and image from a database with react but am having this error anytime i use require(`../../uploads/${this.state.classDt.filename}`) where filename is a state in my component, but if i call the filename directly from my uploads folder it display, if i console.log(this.state.classDt.filename) it works. if i don't use require() it won't display an error but it wont show image or video.. please help.

**my code**

```
import React from 'react'
import ClassWall from './ClassWall'

class ClassSession extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            classDt: [],
            schoolDt:[],
            classtitle:[],
            classDate:[],
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getClassData()
        
    }
    getClassData = async()=>{
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/ClassWalls/media/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
            const Parse = await response.json()
                if(Parse === "can't find class"){
                    console.log('cant find class')
                }else{
                    
                    this.setState({schoolDt:Parse.fileDT.school})
                    this.setState({classtitle:Parse.fileDT.title})
                    this.setState({classDate:Parse.fileDT.date})
                    this.setState({classDt:Parse})
                }
        
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message) 
        }
    }

    render(){
       
        return(
            <div>
                <p>{
                    this.state.classDt.filename
                }</p>
                <video id="1" alt="pic" data-src{require(`../../uploads/${this.state.classDt.filename}`)}></video>
```

**error using require**

```
×
Error: Cannot find module './undefined'
```

Comment: is uploads folder under public directory i.e publicly accessible ?

Comment: what is the response from `http://localhost:4000/ClassWalls/media/${this.props.match.params.id}`
api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<video id="1" alt="pic" 
data-src={(this.state.classDt && this.state.classDt.filename) ? require(`../../uploads/${this.state.classDt.filename}` : '')}
></video>
```

it only ties to require it if `this.state.classDt.filename` exists.

Comment: @princerandy ur welcome :)
plz select it as answer if it helped ;)